# Passing List of Accounts to aura iteration and displaying them in component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, custom-controller, component

I am having an apex class which is having AuraEnabled method which returns list of accounts to . I am able to see the records on console but not able to display the list in component. 
Please help me.

Below is the code:

## Apex class:

```
public class AccountListController {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Account> getAccList(){

        List<Account> accList=new List<Account> ([select id,name,phone from account]);
        return accList;
    }
}
```

## Component:

```
<aura:component controller="AccountListController">

    <Aura:attribute name="accountList" type="Account[]" />

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />

    <aura:iteration items="{!v.accountList}" var="acc">

        {!acc.id}  {!acc.name} {!acc.phone} <br />

    </aura:iteration>

</aura:component>
```

## Controller:

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action=component.get('c.getAccList');
        action.setParams({

        });

        action.setCallback(this,function(response){
        var responseValue=response.getReturnValue();
        console.log('responseValue',responseValue);
        component.set('v.accountList',responseValue)            
        //alert(component.isValid());
        },'SUCCESS');

        $A.enqueueAction(action,false);
    }
})
```

Comment: Try changing `Aura:attribute` to `aura:attribute`. AFAIK the tags are case sensitive.

Comment: @KeithC You are correct. It definitely matters.

Answer (score 1):

Lightning/Aura/LWC/JavaScript is cAsE-sEnSiTiVe. You have a few issues:

```
 Wrong              =>      Right
 Aura:attribute     =>      aura:attribute
 {!acc.id}          =>      {!acc.Id}
 {!acc.name}        =>      {!acc.Name}
 {!acc.phone}       =>      {!acc.Phone}
```

Also, you can return a query directly from a method, no need to go through all the extra steps:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static Account[] getAccList(){
  return [select id,name,phone from account];
}
```

Comment: @sfdcox thanks. Changing id,name & phone to Id,Name & Phone worked.